# Android Telecom self-managed call app, AND custom URI scheme, AND .placeCall for outgoing call >>> how to trigger ConnectionService?

Tags: android, android-connectionservice

The self-managed `PhoneAccount` is being registered like this:

```
PhoneAccount phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle, name)
                .addSupportedUriScheme(CUSTOM_URI_SCHEME)
                .setCapabilities(
                        PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED |
                        PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_VIDEO_CALLING |
                        PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SUPPORTS_VIDEO_CALLING)
                .setShortDescription(name)
                .build();
telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
```

When using `.placeCall()`:

```
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, phoneAccountHandle);
telecomManager.placeCall(Uri.parse(CUSTOM_URI_SCHEME + ":" + "[call address] param"), extra);
```

The `ConnectionService` is not triggered, and below alert message popup:

> Call not sent, no valid number entered.

---

Additionally, I've tested not using custom URI, using "tel:" scheme, found the phone must have SIM card, in order to trigger the `ConnectionService`, this behaviour is not the same as document as self-managed, anyone encountered and able to resolve either the above scenarios?

Comment: You can use VoIP instead of Tel, Tel won't work without a registered Network connection ( Sim Card)

This article may solve your issue: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom#integrateCalling

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that article is what I'm using, which indeed using the telecom framework.

Comment: This problems seems to be API dependent: it works in API 31, fails in API 29 and below (with different error messages) which suggests it's an Android bug.